# document is not defined in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am a total beginner in TypeScript and trying to build a simple register service with it, but somehow I get this error

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\WebstormProjects\myhttp\dist\index.js:8:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

And here is my code, I know it is short and incomplete but how can I handle with document?

```
 class User  {
        name:string;
        surname:string;
        // constructor
        constructor(name:string , surname:string) {
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
        }
    }

    let userArray: User[] = [];

    let addUser = document.getElementById("add-user-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
        let userName = document.getElementById("user-name-val").nodeValue;
        let userSurname = document.getElementById("user-surname-val").nodeValue;
        userArray.push(new User(userName,userSurname));

    });
```

Comment: It seems you're executing this code in NodeJS, and not in a browser. So why do you think there should be a document? What would this document be?

Comment: Yes I am executing in NodeJS and also I don't know the difference, I just want to get username and surname from a localhost page.

Comment: Look at this page. There is some code running in the browser, and whch has access to the document (like, for example, the code which counts how many characters I can still type in the comment). And then I submit the comment and it's sent to the stackoverflow web server. The web server has accee to the http request, and can send back a response, but it doesn't have access to the browser document. NodeJS is a technology which allows executing code **on the server**, not in the browser.

Comment: I get that logic, thank you! But, still I cannot figure out how to achieve my goal.

Comment: By writing a script that is included into a web page loaded in the browser, instead of executing code in NodeJS.

Comment: Hey yesterday there was a github link, that was really helpful! Could you post it again?